# Instances in Java

Tags: java, instance, instance-variables

I have 4 classes; `RunSO`, `MyGUI`, `MyMenuBar`, and `NumberSettingsFile`.I have an instance of `NumberSettingsFile` in `MyGUI` and `MyMenuBar`. The problem is they are separate instances so when I use methods in one instance it does not update the values in the second instance. My question how would I get these instances to work in unison. For example if I set the value of `sortComboBox` to `11`. It updates the instance of `NumberSettingsFile` in the `MyMenuBar` but not in `MyGUI`. So when the button is pressed the value given will still be `10`. How would I get it to update the value in both instances so that when I press the button it would give out the value `11` (in this case).

The code for the 4 classes are as follows.

**NumberSettingsFile**

```
package SO;

public class NumberSettingsFile
{
    int numberSetting1 = 10;

    public int getNumberSetting1()
    {
        return numberSetting1;
    }

    public void setNumberSetting1(int newNumberSetting1)
    {
        numberSetting1 = newNumberSetting1;
    }
}
```

**MyMenuBar**

```
package SO;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MyMenuBar extends JMenuBar
{
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    NumberSettingsFile uniSet = new NumberSettingsFile();
    JComboBox sortComboBox;
    MyGUI mG;

    public MyMenuBar(MyGUI mG)
    {
        this.mG = mG;
        setBorderPainted(true);
        makeMenuBar();
    }

    public void makeMenuBar()
    {       
        countTo(20);
        sortComboBox = new JComboBox(list.toArray());
        sortComboBox.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,25));
        sortComboBox.addItemListener(new sortComboBoxChanged());
        add(sortComboBox);
        sortComboBox.setSelectedItem(uniSet.getNumberSetting1());
    }

    public void countTo(int C)
    {
        for(int k =2; k<=C; k++)
        {
            list.add(k);
        }
    }

    class sortComboBoxChanged implements ItemListener
    {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
        {
            String s = sortComboBox.getSelectedItem()+"";
            uniSet.setNumberSetting1(Integer.parseInt(s));
            System.out.println("This is the number which should be shown if you click the button: "+uniSet.getNumberSetting1());
        }
    }
}
```

**MyGUI**

```
package SO;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MyGUI
{
    JFrame exampleFrame = new JFrame("Example");
    JPanel examplePanel = new JPanel();
    JButton exButton = new JButton();

    NumberSettingsFile uniSet = new NumberSettingsFile();
    MyMenuBar mbr;

    public void runGUI()
    {
        exampleFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        exampleFrame.setBounds(10,10,250,180);

        exampleFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

        createExamplePanel();

        mbr = new MyMenuBar(this);

        exampleFrame.setJMenuBar(mbr);

        exampleFrame.getContentPane().add(examplePanel);

        exampleFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void createExamplePanel()
    {
        examplePanel.setLayout(null);

        exButton.setBounds(10,10,100,100);
        exButton.setText("<html><CENTER>Press Me</CENTER></html>");
        exButton.addActionListener(new CustomActionListener());
        examplePanel.add(exButton);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyGUI mG = new MyGUI();
        mG.runGUI();
    }

    class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getSource() == exButton)
            {
                System.out.println("This is the number which is shown if you click the button: "+uniSet.getNumberSetting1());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**RunSO.java**

```
import SO.*;

public class RunSO
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        RunSO rS = new RunSO();
        MyGUI.main(args);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help with this matter.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "work in unison".  But if you want a class to have a single set of variables separate from any given instance of that class then you can make those variables static.

Comment: @David I updated the question. I hope that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to share one instance of `NumberSettingsFile` between your two objects. To do that, you should avoid creating it inside the classes, and instead, create it where you create the two classes, and pass them the shared instance.

In this case, one of your classes is already the one that creates an instance of the other. So you should pass along the instance of the `NumberSettingsFile`:

In `MyMenuBar`, instead of creating an instance:

```
NumberSettingsFile uniSet = new NumberSettingsFile();
```

Just declare without initializing:

```
NumberSettingsFile uniSet;
```

Then change the constructor:

```
public MyMenuBar(MyGUI mG, NumberSettingsFile uniSet)
{
    this.mG = mG;
    this.uniSet = uniSet;
    setBorderPainted(true);
    makeMenuBar();
}
```

Then, in `MyGui`, change the creation of the menu bar:

```
mbr = new MyMenuBar(this, uniSet);
```

Now there is only one single instance shared between the GUI and the menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating multiple instances just pass the one instance to both classes when creating them? or would that not work.

```
   BaseClass has new NumberSettingFileInstance nsfi
      |                    |
new MyMenuBar(nsfi)     new MyGUI(nsfi)
```

I hope my crude ASCII art diagram can explain something.

Comment: I think I understand what you are getting at. Thanks for the help, however realskeptics answer works perfectly.

Comment: Essentially realskeptics answer was exactly the same as mine in idea just executed differently - glad you solved your issue :)